# Event subprocess vs Call activity

Tags: activiti

I aim to start a subprocess based on a certain user action in a user task(user task remains incomplete), and return back to original process on its completion.

Going through activi documentation, I understand I can have two approaches. One approach can be to make use of Event subprocess and another approach can be to use Call activity.

Due to my limited knowledge of Activiti framework, I am not able to decide which one should I opt for.

I also aim to have subprocess reusable as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You have one problem here in that you indicate you dont want the user task to complete.
Either the call activity or exet sub process will work, but both require that the user task completes. That is, unless you add some fancy UI element that uses the rest API to make the event call.

Now, considering the user task has to complete (if we dont have a fancy UI), there is noting to stop you re-entering the user task and repopulating the variables that had previously been populated.